# Fatal Error (time-out) when trying to Export Customers from Magento 1.3.1

Tags: fatal-error

I recently setup a brand new fresh install of Magento 1.9.1. I have an old Magento store 1.3.1. After I've put in all the products by hand, I realized that my customers are missing their login accounts! The thing is - there are 2100 registered customers! When I try to EXPORT CUSTOMERS - I get the following Errors:

Starting profile execution, please wait...
Warning: Please don't close window during importing/exporting data

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/MYstore/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 406

---

Starting profile execution, please wait...
Warning: Please don't close window during importing/exporting data

### Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/MYstore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Batch.php on line 98

Thanks for any ideas! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP configuration file (`php.ini`) increase `max_execution_time` value.

You can also do this in `index.php` (just above `error_reporting` line) but I would not recommend this for all the requests as some request can go really long which you may not want. May be do it until your purpose is served: `set_time_limit(0)` - this completely disables time limit.

Comment: My index.ini looks like this: extension=pdo.so 
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so      and I don't have an error_reporting line in the index.php.....How exactly do I put that code in there? Just enter "set_time_limit(0)" ? Thank you.

Comment: No in your magento `index.php` file. It should at the root of the project.